# SQLAlchemy model @property with query for another model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm currently working on migrating a Flask application from the `Flask-SQLAlchemy` package to the `SQLAlchemy 1.4.2` package. With the Flask-SQLAlchemy model, I can do something like this:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Author(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'authors'
    
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    surname = db.Column(db.String)

class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    year = db.Column(db.Integer)
    author_id = db.Column(db.String)
    
    @property
    def author(self):
        return Author.query.get(self.author_id)
```

I can then access the `author` property on a `Book` object and it returns me an `Author` object. Let's say I know a book and I want to get info about the author like this:

```py
book: Book = Book.query.get(book_id)
author: Author = book.author
```

However, with the `SQLAlchemy`, I have to use `session.get`, which means I would have to pass my current session as a parameter:

```
class Book(db.Model):
    ...
    
    def author(self, session):
        return session.get(Author, author_id)
```

Is there a way to preserve the simplicity of `book.author` while using the `SQLAlchemy` package? I have little experience with the pure `SQLAlchemy`, so if you can push me in the right direction, it will be appreciated.

**Edit:**
In my case, at the time of adding the book, the author is not necessarily known to the system yet, causing an error because of an unknown foreign key in the case of the relationship solution.

Comment: You could define a [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one) between the two tables, then `Book.author` could work even without defining a property.

Comment: What @snakecharmerb wrote is the proper solution, but in general for properties that need the session the object is bound to use `object_session()`: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.object_session

Comment: @snakecharmerb comment is the solution with one caveat: your relationship is ["One to Many"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-one) _(not "One to One")_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the question edit, the author (or its equivalent in the real problem I'm working on) is not necessarily known at the time of adding the book. In case I'm adding a book when the author is not known yet, the program raises an error because of an unknown foreign key when I'm using a relationship. Therefore, the correct solution in this case is the one proposed by [Ilja Everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66875017/sqlalchemy-model-property-with-query-for-another-model?noredirect=1#comment118215994_66875017). The solution then looks like:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import object_session

...

class Book(db.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def author(self):
        return object_session(self).get(Author, self.author_id)
```